# Output SSH keys using Azure CLI

Tags: azure

When we ran the Azure CLI command to create a new ssh key, It will store the PEM & PUB keys in **.ssh/** folder.

but we need to store it on separate folder.
Here is the command Azure CLI

```
az sshkey create --name "test-ssh" --resource-group "azure-dev"
```

But we are using the Bash script to store the PEM & PUB Key in separate folder.

```
az sshkey create --name "test-ssh" --resource-group "azure-dev" >> /home/ubuntu/keyrotation-az/creds/test-ssh
```

Output was storing in JSON format, But we need to store it on separate folder.

How can we store it on separate folder not in **.ssh** folder.